# Compiler Error. compiled c++ .exe is 16 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, windows-10, cygwin

I want to compile Hello World in c++ in visual studio code in Windows 10.
I installed the c++ extension and the cygwin64 compiler and modified the files task.json, launch.json and c_cpp_properties.json but when I try to run build task it produces an hello.exe file that cannot be opened

The error message is something like this:
Unsupported 16-bit Application. The program or feature "....exe"
cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the
software vendor to ask if a 64-bit compatible version is available.

As if the compiler made a 16bit application instead of a 64bit one.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Unless you absolutely need cygwin for compatibility reasons, you'll probably find the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) is a far better experience.

Comment: Can you include the code you tried to compile plus the exact logs from your compilation attempt?

Comment: As I said the code is for the simple Hello World.

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

Comment: ...plus the *exact logs from your compilation attempt*. Don't say "The error message was something like..." we need to see the actual output.

Comment: it's in Italian, the error message I posted is the translation

Comment: It's quite  odd to me that a modern compiler would produce 16 bit executables by default. I am confused how you got in this situation.

Comment: If you want help it's usually not too hard to temporarily flip your locale and capture the errors as they appear in English. This helps *considerably* with debugging.

Comment: I second that you probably don't want Cygwin. Its primary purpose is compiling non-portable software that was written for Linux, and wouldn't compile for Windows otherwise. Also I don't think WSL is a good choice if you're planning to distribute your programs to other people (which might now have WSL installed). You should use MinGW. You can get an up-to-date version from https://www.msys2.org/ or http://winlibs.com/ .

Comment: I don't buy the distribution argument at this level. Is cmake sufficient, or would you be setting up a cross-compiliation environment regardless? Or just mark in the README that it requires Linux. But for Windows-native, I do support getting MinGW from MSYS2.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat can you guide me on what to do after installing msys2?

Comment: If you're looking to make Windows executables you may want to steer towards a full copy of Visual Studio Community. If you're just hacking around, WSL is probably the way to go.

Comment: Short answer: open MSYS2 terminal, run `pacman -Syuu` to update the packages (if MSYS2 exits in the process, restart it and run the same command again to complete the update). Then run `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` to install the compiler. Assuming you installed MSYS2 into `C:\msys64`, your compiler will be in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and what do I write in task.json and c_cpp_properties.json?

Comment: You should only need to change compiler path. Can you show us what you have in those files?

Answer (score -1):

Update `task.json` and add:

```
"-m64":
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-m64",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\cpp.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This should be unnecessary. The compiler in `mingw64\bin` already targets x64 by default.